# Getting 'delete impacts too many records' when deleting records using supabase

Tags: graphql, supabase

I'm currently using Supabase together with Graphql and trying to delete some data using a mutation. Unfortunately this mutation sometimes fails and gives me back an error that tells me that the `delete impacts too many records`. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

The mutation I'm using is:

```js
mutation UnfollowUser($followerUserId: UUID, $followingUserId: UUID) {
  deleteFromfollowsCollection(filter: {follower: {eq: $followerUserId}, following: {eq: $followingUserId}}){
    affectedCount
  }
}
```

Comment: Supabase has a safeguard that prevents you from accidentally deleting bunch of records. In this example, it seems like the intended behavior is to delete one row, but is that correct? You might be accidentally trying to delete more records than you think. I would double check that you have the correct filters in place to only target the rows that you intend to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it does not seem to be documented anywhere, it turns out that supabase's pg_graphql has an `atMost` property. This can be used to limit the number of deleted records, and by default seems to be equal to 1.

Using this property we can adjust the previously decribed mutation, and allow it to delete up to 10 records at a time.

```js
mutation UnfollowUser($followerUserId: UUID, $followingUserId: UUID) {
  deleteFromfollowsCollection(filter: {follower: {eq: $followerUserId}, following: {eq: $followingUserId}}, atMost: 10){
    affectedCount
  }
}
```

[Reference](https://github.com/supabase/pg_graphql/blob/be162c5613cbb18d3f4796f079819e2ef0e30bd6/test/expected/mutation_delete_variable.out)